# Trying to remove an element from a vector by value

Tags: c++, vector

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)
```

When I am doing

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), valToRemove), vec.end());
```

valToRemove is an int.

Comment: Can you make a SSCCE?

Comment: I don't think so. Program's pretty crazy. I just don't understand the error so I don't know where to look.

Comment: have you included `<algorithm>`?

Comment: TY @Nim! Missing include indeed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were most likely trying to call [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) function instead the correct one. Probably you don't have `<algorithm>` included so the compiler can't see the overloaded version of the function.